# Flush input buffer in Racket

Tags: serial-port, racket

I have a serial port input in Racket, and I want to only read the new incoming data when I check it. In Python, I can easily do this with `my_serial_port.flush()` before reading. However, I can't figure out how to do something analogous in Racket. When I just read from the port with `(read-bytes 1 in-port))`, I'm getting "old" data that I want to flush out before reading.

There is a [`flush-output`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/port-buffers.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._flush-output%29%29) function, but I can't find anything analogous for flushing the input buffer. I've tried a variety of things on that page, but nothing seems to achieve this functionality. It seems like this should be pretty straightforward, so I feel like I must be missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're talking about two slightly different uses of the word ``flush.'' In the case of the output buffers, flushing ensures that buffered data is actually sent to the port. In your case, you're talking about discarding input data.

This is probably the right way to do what you want (the code includes an example input port to show how it works)

```
#lang racket

(define buf-size 20000)

;; given a port, allocate a buffer of size 'buf-size' and
;; repeatedly read available bytes or specials until 0
;; bytes are available.
(define (drain-port port)
  (define buf (make-bytes buf-size))
  (let loop ()
    (define try-read (read-bytes-avail!* buf port))
    (cond [(or (eof-object? try-read)
               (and (number? try-read) (= try-read 0)))
           'done]
          [else
           (loop)])))

(define example-port (open-input-string "abcdef"))
(drain-port example-port)
```